# Definition of subgame perfect Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, dynamic-games

Take a two-stage game with complete information and simultaneous actions in each state:

(1) Player 1 and 2 simultaneously choose action $a_1\in A_1$  and
$a_2\in A_2$ respectively.

(2) Player 1 and 2 observe the outcome of the 1st stage
$(a_1, a_2)$, then simultaneously choose action  $a_3\in A_3$ and
$a_4\in A_4$ respectively.

Payoffs are $u_i(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$ for $i = 1,2$.

---

As equilibrium concept I use subgame perfect Nash equilibrium. I find it by
backward induction:

(A) find the **functions** $a^*_3(\cdot)$  and $a^*_4(\cdot)$ such that $\forall (a_1,a_2)\in A_1\times A_2$

$$
\begin{cases}
a_3^*(a_1, a_2)\in argmax_{a_3(\cdot)}u_1(a_1, a_2, a_3(a_1, a_2), a_4(a_1, a_2))\\
a_4^*(a_1, a_2)\in argmax_{a_4(\cdot)}u_2(a_1, a_2, a_3(a_1, a_2), a_4(a_1, a_2))\\
\end{cases}
$$

(B) find $(a_1^*, a_2^*)\in A_1\times A_2$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
a_1^*\in argmax_{a_1}u_1(a_1, a_2, a^*_3(a_1, a_2), a^*_4(a_1, a_2))\\
a_2^*\in argmax_{a_2}u_2(a_1, a_2, a^*_3(a_1, a_2), a^*_4(a_1, a_2))\\
\end{cases}
$$

---

Question: a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium is
$$
\{a_1^*, a_2^*, \underbrace{a^*_3(\cdot), a^*_4(\cdot)}_{\text{Functions}}\}
$$
or
$$
\{a_1^*, a_2^*, \underbrace{a^*_3(a_1^*), a^*_4(a_2^*)}_{\text{Point in the image set of the functions $a^*_3(\cdot), a^*_4(\cdot)$}}\}
$$
?

Comment: The equilibrium MUST include the functions and not just the point. If you only specified, e.g., $a^*_3(a_1^*)$ then how could you evaluate if a deviation from $a_1^*$ when it is not specified what happens afterwards (and thus you don't know the payoff)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equilibrium consists of a profile of *strategies*, which specifies an action for every player at each possible contingency. Since each action profile $(a_1,a_2)$ is a contingency, the SPE must include functions $a^*_3(a_1,a_2), a^*_4(a_1,a_2)$ that specifies what to do at those contingencies.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to ask one minor thing and I don't feel it is worth to be part of a separate question. Would you be so kind to reply? My question is: let $\{a_1^*, a_2^*, a_3^*(\cdot), a_4^*(\cdot)\}$ be a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium of the game above; take $(a_1^*, a_2^*, a_3^*(a_1^*), a_4^*(a_2^*))$; is there any specific terminology to indicate this last vector of points? I would say that "it is part" of a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium, but I'm wondering whether I can refer to it in a more technical way. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3285148: The vector of points you mentioned is called the *equilibrium outcome* of the SPE.